# blender sculpting not smooth

Tags: sculpting

trying to sculpt wood in blender but it's not smooth for some reason, what should I do?

[image]

[image]

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/jTp0u3c I don't know how to add more than one picture to the post sorry

Comment: First thing, it looks like you haven't shaded smooth? You may not be able to have a better result with your current topology, in that case you need to use the Dyntopo option, or the Multiresolution modifier

Comment: You need more geometry, try dynotopo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now you have very uneven geometry. All of the faces on this cylinder are thin rectangle shapes.

[image]

When sculpting you generally want to get as even of geometry as possible.

There are a few ways to get this effect.

The "cleaner" way. This preserves perfect quads and edge-loops, can be un-subdivided later etc.

Ctrl+Alt+Click to select all the edge rings.

[image]

Then *Select > Loops > Edge Loops* to expand those along the whole mesh.

[image: edge loops]

[image]

Then right click > Subdivide. Change the number of cuts until your geo looks like this. Much more square than before.

[image]

At this point you can use a Multiresolution modifier to subdivide it further non destructively. If you use a Multires before doing this though it will just make a mesh with the same issues only smaller.

**Multires applied without subdivided edges first:**

[image]

If you don't care about what the geo looks like long term then you can also just use voxel/quad remesher to even it out at the resolution you want.

Voxel Remesher: *Fast, more forgiving, messy geo.*

[image]

Quad Remesher: *Slower, Doesn't work on non-manifold meshes, super clean geo*

[image]

Comment: For a simple cylinder, I think the sculpt mode's remesh is more than enough

Comment: Yeah I like to "teach a person to fish" rather than just give them the fish ya know. Help them understand why his issue is happening rather than just tell them what buttons to click.